# Why does Select turn my while loop into an infinite loop?

Tags: c#, linq

At work I ran into a strange problem, where a loop I *expected to terminate* was actually *running indefinitely*.

I traced the problem back to a use of `Select`.
Interestingly, the *loop terminated* as expected when I added a `.ToList()` right after the `Select`. I boiled it down to a small example.

```cs
class WrappedBool
{
    public WrappedBool(bool inner)
    {
        InnerBool = inner;
    }
    public bool InnerBool { get; set; } = false;
}

// remove .ToList() here and the following loop will go infinite
IEnumerable<WrappedBool> enumerable = 
   new List<bool>() { false, true, false }
  .Select(b => new WrappedBool(b))
  .ToList();

while (enumerable.Any(wb => !wb.InnerBool))
{
    WrappedBool firstFalse = enumerable.Where(wb => !wb.InnerBool).First();
    firstFalse.InnerBool = true;
}
```

While I don't have to deal with my code not terminating anymore, I still wonder where this behaviour is coming from in the first place.

Comment: .Any enumerates the List, causing te Constructor to trigger. Therefore, on every .Any, 3 new objects are created with 2 being False, going infinite.
You can see this by breaking on the Constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, without *materialization* (`.ToList()`) `enumerable` is just a query

```
IEnumerable<WrappedBool> enumerable = 
   new List<bool>() { false, true, false }
  .Select(b => new WrappedBool(b));
```

whenever you call it, it creates a *new instance* of `List<bool>() {false, true, false}` where you have `false` items to iterate on

```
// new List<bool>() { false, true, false } - do we have any false item here?
// Yes - keep on looping (forever)
while (enumerable.Any(wb => !wb.InnerBool)) 
{
    // get 1st false from new List<bool>() { false, true, false }
    WrappedBool firstFalse = enumerable.Where(wb => !wb.InnerBool).First();
    // turn it into true and discard
    firstFalse.InnerBool = true;
}
```

On the contrary

```
IEnumerable<WrappedBool> enumerable = 
   new List<bool>() { false, true, false }
  .Select(b => new WrappedBool(b))
  .ToList(); // create a List; call new List<bool>() { false, true, false } just once
```

is *materialized* so `enumerable` is `List<T>` which is created *once* and in which you modify 1st and 3d items:

```
// does enumerable collection (List) have any false item? 
while (enumerable.Any(wb => !wb.InnerBool)) 
{
    // get 1st false from enumerable List
    WrappedBool firstFalse = enumerable.Where(wb => !wb.InnerBool).First();
    // turn it into true 
    firstFalse.InnerBool = true;
}
```

Comment: Is it really creating a new instance of the initial List every time?
I think the problem is rather creating the new WrappedBool in the Select every time.

Comment: @Pseudoradius: Linq uses *deffered execution*; it does nothing until called and perform query each time you call it. Materialization turns *query* into a *collection* (`.ToList()`, `.ToArray()`), *value* (`.Count()`) and does it *once*; then you work with this collection, value etc. as usual.

Comment: I think I understand it now. Thanks for your help. :)